# How can I check the current ostream dec/hex mode when writing my own streaming operator?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple class that has a friend for writing to an output stream such as `std::cout`.

The state of my class can be represented in numerical form, and I might want to see that in decimal or hex.

If I were printing a POD `int`, I could use the `std::hex` modifier; what I'd like to do is check that in my function and act accordingly.  So far my searches have drawn a blank.

```
class Example
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Example& e );
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Example& e )
{
    if ( /*check for hex mode*/ )
        o << "hexadecimal";
    else
        o << "decimal";
    return o;
}
```

What should I use in place of `/*check for hex mode*/` ?

EDIT: I made my example super-generic.

Comment: Look at [std::ios_base::flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `flags()` function of the `ostream` and see if the `hex` bit is set:

```cpp
bool isHexMode(std::ostream& os) {
    return (os.flags() & std::ios_base::hex) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, with thanks to @AProgrammer for pointing me in the right direction.

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Example& e )
{
    if ( o.flags() & std::ios_base::hex )  // <-----
        o << "hexadecimal";
    else
        o << "not hexadecimal";
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is also the possibility of octal.  Thus when it isn't hexadecimal that does not mean it is decimal.

Comment: You're right.  I've made a tongue-in-cheek edit to my answer.